# Sun shadow from buildings on Mapbox GL 3D

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to project sun-shadows from buildings using Mapbox GL 3D. I found this plugin example [Shademap](https://shademap.app/@48.2326,16.41778,15.7269z,1677841444048t,-112.65731b,33.5p,0m) but it's working with a server response and I want to resolve it just in local.

I did some draft working with fill-extrusion properties using [SunCalc](https://github.com/mourner/suncalc) library to get the  sun position, for a given datetime.

SunCalc returns an object with the following properties:

- altitude: sun altitude above the horizon in radians
- azimuth: sun azimuth in radians (direction along the horizon, measured from south to west)

So, is easy to displace the building fill-extrusion:

```
'fill-extrusion-translate': [sunPosition.azimuth - 180, 0]
```

But this is not a shadow projection it's just a displacement. I need to project the shadow as the left example bellow, not a simple displacement like at the right.

[image]

Even (desirably) I want to apply some blur to the fill. I couldn't find how to do it with mapbox, I don't know if its possible. I found a property to blur lines, not fill.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShadeMap author here. I put together a gist that uses a Mapbox custom layer to accomplish building shadows locally (you must of course be connected to load the Mapbox tile data which contains the building footprints and heights themselves)

Github issue thread for building shadows: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7976

Gist of Mapbox example with building shadows: https://gist.github.com/ted-piotrowski/420a31bf3c157664fdda14bf45692785

Comment: Hi @teddybeard thanks so much for your gist, very useful. I have an offset between buildings and shadows, but I can fix it myself. All the best!